# Groovy Conversion - From Java

Tags: java, groovy, maven-3

I have the following small part of a java class:

```
public class GBitMaskTest {

    @Test
    public void checkFirstBitTest() {
        BitMask bm = new BitMask(0x8000000000000000L);
        assertEquals(true, bm.isBitSet(63));
    }

...
}
```

which should be compilable in Groovy as well cause it's valid Java code. But i get the following:

```
Groovy Bug --- exception in phase 'conversion' in source unit '/home/g-ut-example/src/test/groovy/com/soebes/training/maven/simple/GBitMaskTest.groovy' For input string: "8000000000000000"
BUG! exception in phase 'conversion' in source unit '/home/g-ut-example/src/test/groovy/com/soebes/training/maven/simple/GBitMaskTest.groovy' For input string: "8000000000000000"
```

May be i misunderstand a thing. Someone an idea?

This has happened with Groovy 2.0 in relationship with Maven. It's this example https://github.com/khmarbaise/maui/tree/master/src/main/resources/g-ut-example which produces this problem. I'm compiling with the following part:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
          <compilerArgument>nowarn</compilerArgument>
          <verbose>true</verbose>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0-01</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-01</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

The rest of the error message (EXception):

```
GBitMaskTest.groovy' For input string: "8000000000000000"
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:1001)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:624)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:600)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:577)
    at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.internal.compiler.ast.GroovyCompilationUnitDeclaration.processToPhase(GroovyCompilationUnitDeclaration.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.internal.compiler.ast.GroovyParser.dietParse(GroovyParser.java:455)
    at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.integration.internal.MultiplexingParser.dietParse(MultiplexingParser.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.internalBeginToCompile(Compiler.java:775)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.beginToCompile(Compiler.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.Main.performCompilation(Main.java:3829)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.Main.compile(Main.java:1682)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.compiler.GroovyEclipseCompiler.compile(GroovyEclipseCompiler.java:243)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:678)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.TestCompilerMojo.execute(TestCompilerMojo.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8000000000000000"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:422)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.Numbers.parseInteger(Numbers.java:215)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.integerExpression(AntlrParserPlugin.java:3184)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.expressionSwitch(AntlrParserPlugin.java:2153)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.expression(AntlrParserPlugin.java:2018)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.expression(AntlrParserPlugin.java:2008)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.expressionSwitch(AntlrParserPlugin.java:2046)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.expression(AntlrParserPlugin.java:2018)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.expression(AntlrParserPlugin.java:2008)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.addArgumentExpression(AntlrParserPlugin.java:3071)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.arguments(AntlrParserPlugin.java:2994)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.constructorCallExpression(AntlrParserPlugin.java:2932)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.expressionSwitch(AntlrParserPlugin.java:2069)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.expression(AntlrParserPlugin.java:2018)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.expression(AntlrParserPlugin.java:2008)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.declarationExpression(AntlrParserPlugin.java:1776)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.variableDef(AntlrParserPlugin.java:1792)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.statement(AntlrParserPlugin.java:1513)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.statementListNoChild(AntlrParserPlugin.java:1599)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.statementList(AntlrParserPlugin.java:1574)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.methodDef(AntlrParserPlugin.java:1045)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.objectBlock(AntlrParserPlugin.java:800)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.innerClassDef(AntlrParserPlugin.java:783)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.classDef(AntlrParserPlugin.java:677)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.convertGroovy(AntlrParserPlugin.java:361)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.buildAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:269)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.convert(SourceUnit.java:302)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$3.call(CompilationUnit.java:706)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:992)
    ... 35 more
```

Comment: Which version of groovy? I assume this is a junit test?

Comment: Groovy Version 2. Updated my question and information accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised this compiles in Java, since 0x8000000000000000L is larger than `Long.MAX_VALUE`.  It looks like Java treats it as an unsigned value.  I'd recommend using -0x8000000000000000L instead, since it's the same bit value, but falls within the legal range for longs and works in both Java and groovy.

Edit: According to the [Java Language Specification §3.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1), decimal literals above `Long.MAX_VALUE` are illegal but hexidecimal literals *aren't*, so long as they fit in 64 bits.  So this appears to be valid Java.

Comment: +1 Shouldn't cause a BUG! verifier exception though... Could be with adding to the jira if it falls with groovy 2

Comment: 0x8000000000000000L this is exactly the value of Long.MIN_VALUE which should be compilable in my opinion and it's of course greater than Long.MAX_VALUE, cause Long.MAX_VALUE is the largest positive value whereas 0x8000000000000000L is the largest negative value.

Comment: 0x8000000000000000L should be compilable in Java at least, since it's specifically allowed in the language spec.  It is equivalent to `Long.MIN_VALUE` but it's actually interpreted to be less than `Long.MAX_VALUE`.  It's a negative value since it overflows into the sign bit.